# Setup Game Center Leaderboard so it's a counter

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

Is it possible to set up a Game Center leaderboard so it the "score" is persistent ? I want to use leaderboards to show the number of wins a player has, but I don't see how it's possible to just increase a counter with a leaderboard, is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **NSUserDefaults** to save and Retrieve data (number of wins) 
Example :

```
//ViewController.h :    
NSInteger NbrOfWins ; 




//ViewController.m :
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
//...
[super viewDidLoad];
// ...

//Retrieving data
NbrOfWins = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"Wins"];

}




-(void)NewWin{
//...

NbrOfWins = NbrOfWins + 1 ;

//Saving data
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:NbrOfWins forKey:@"Wins"];

//Calling a Game Center function to send the new number of wins :
[self reportScore];
}



//Game center functions 
-(void)reportScore{
// Create a GKScore object to assign the score and report it as a NSArray object.
GKScore *score = [[GKScore alloc] initWithLeaderboardIdentifier:_leaderboardIdentifier];

//Sending the new number of wins :
score.value = NbrOfWins;

[GKScore reportScores:@[score] withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
  }];
}

// ... Other game center functions please see the documentation
```

More info about Game Center implementation :
http://www.appcoda.com/ios-game-kit-framework/

More info about **NSUserDefaults** : 
http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using Parse.com so saving the wins is not the issue, the issue is how to get GC to display that as a table of wins, because if you just submit the number of wins it will just keep being a new score, but what I need is for it to keep one score so to speak, and keep updating it.

Comment: @Phil What do you mean with GC ?

Comment: @Phil what do you want to display in GC ? The number of wins only or other informations ?

Comment: Number of wins. But obviously this needs to be a persistent value, in other words it cannot be a new number submitted each time, it needs to be a number which is updated, and then Game Center displays them.

Comment: I don't know where is the problem ? With the previous code : For example if your number of wins is 7 then when you win an other time the number will change to 8 ! So where is the problem we send the new number (old number+1) to gc and it will update the value :)

Comment: How will it know to update the value? wouldn't it just put a new value into the leaderboard?

Comment: We have saved the old value in the device , when you win the value will become : new value = old value + 1 then the new value will be sent to GC it's an update ! isn't it  ?

Comment: Yes, but let's say I win a game, and I submit that to the leaderboard, so the leaderboard has me = 1 then I win again, and I submit that again, won't it just have 2 scores from me? or are you saying it will just keep updating the same score?

Comment: I think that is what you are looking for isn't it ?